# integrate Xcode and xamarin projects in single project

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am creating an iOS app. One of my team member wants to work on Xcode and other wants to use Xamarin. I want to know that is it possible that both modules can be be integrated into a single project in the end?

Comment: you can create binding projects that allow Obj-C libraries to be accessed from C#.  However, doing this simply to suit the personal preferences of your dev team seems like a really bad approach.

Comment: I would dissuade to use Xamarin. The community is not that big and there is a lot of bad solutions for so many things. The compilation process is horrible (If one of the guy would work on the Windows).

Comment: @Hassan Unfortunately that is not possible.. You three will need to decide what's best for your project and that will really depends on you 3. How confident you feel with Xcode or Visual Studio as well as your knowledge with Swift vs C#.

Comment: The good part about Xamarin is that you can share a lot of code between platforms. Even some GUI code if you use Xamarin Forms. I wouldn't recommend taking the Xamarin approach for iOS only application, and even less if one of the developers is already using native approach.

Answer (score 0):

Practically - No.

In theory - Yes, you can manage to develop some parts of the application in Xamarin, some parts in Xcode and then combine them. But practically it won't pay back in time/effort perspective. Xcode and Xamarin are not just different IDEs, it's completely differents approach of developing an application.